# how to get direction from my gps location to one location from many given locations as destination using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gps

I want to find the location nearest my gps location, from many given coordinates.
Example:
i have 3 coordinates that i want to put into the program as my destinations but i just want to go to one location that  nearest from my current(gps) location.

I'm using this intent to show direction from my location to one given location.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=destcoordinat"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Can I use intent in this problem or there is any other solution?

**EDIT**

somehow i just got the answer but i know there is any better solution.
here if you want to know.

1. I need to calculate the distance from my location to the three given location
2. Put the the distance result in arraylist
3. Find the minimum by using minValue = Collections.min(distanceArray);
4. Using if else condition to find what coordinate is nearest the user location
   {if(distance1<=minValue){
    using intent to get the direction to location1
    } 
    else if(distance2<=minValue){
    using intent to get the direction to location2
    }
    .....
5. Finally the program can choose the nearest place that i have to go and giving me the
   direction Navigation.

*I know this is not a best solution cause i have to put manually the coordinate into (intent).

Thank you for your answers I really appreciate that, but if you have any other solution please Comment below.

Comment: can you elaborate your question?

Comment: @Harshid i'm trying to make program that can choose one coordinate from many coordinate that i put in the program..after the program have choosen one coordinate, i'm going to use the intent to show the direction..is it possible to do that?